# Debian Bionic bug in Artifactory Jfrog

Tags: debian, artifactory, jfrog-cli

according to this ticket - https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16378
older Artifactory is not supporting Bionic Debian Repos.
We are trying to override that problem and after uploading the *.deb file we generating Packages files and upload them to the Artifactory.

```
dpkg-scanpackages . | tee Packages
bzip2 -k Packages
gzip -c Packages > Packages.gz
```

However, there is a problem since 'Release' file stays not updated and contains an old Checksums values. We tried to reindex the repo but the command also reindexing the 'Packages' file. :(

```
# Reindex debian repo, Regenerate Release files
curl -u $JFROG_USER:$JFROG_PASS -X POST $ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/deb/reindex/$REPOSITORY
```

Is there any option to overcome that Jfrog bug?

Answer (score 1):

we used that solution as a workaround: https://github.com/utopia-repository/qt5ct/commit/c5229c6e938f76397401da695f8deaabede97b4d

Add to the debian rules file:

```
override_dh_builddeb:
    # Temporary workaround for https://github.com/smira/aptly/issues/655
    dh_builddeb -- -Zgzip
```

That solution forces gzip compression during a debian creation process.

Answer (score 0):

When Artifactory runs an index op (or reindex) it will:

1. Collect all relevant deb packages to index
2. Build all `packages` indices
3. Build the `Release` index
4. Populate acquire-by-hash folder hierarchy

Simply put, you can't place packages indices and reindex - Artifactory will override the files you deployed.

You can also calculate the Release index if possible and deploy it as well but be aware that on any deployment you make to that repo the indices will get overwritten by Artifactory's index operation.

You might be able to workaround this by duplicating the index file structure in a `generic repo` and deploying your own indices there (you also need the deb files to be present for apt to be able to download them) but this is a real overkill.

Best solution for you is just to upgrade to 6.1.0 where this bug was fixed.